# How to use jquery selector to select Bootstrap Modal with {{ $item->id }}

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I noticed that when the select2 is in a modal, the search input is not focusable, also the up and down keys are not working too.
jquery: 3.6.1
select2: 4.1.0

i want to use jquery selector to find/select select2 search input in a my bootstrap modal with {{ $item->id }} for example.

```
<div class="modal modal-end" tabindex="-1" id="edit{{ $item->id }}" aria-labelledby="modalRightLabel">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 id="modalRightLabel">EDIT FRUIT</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="modal " aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/fruit/{{ $item->id }}" method="POST">
           {{ method_field('put') }}
           {{ csrf_field('') }}
    
           <div class="form-group mb-3">
               <label class="form-label">Fruit name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fruit" value="{{ $item->fruit_name}}" placeholder="Fruit Name" required>
                </div>
    
    
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                 <label class="form-label">Category</label>
                 <select name="category" class="js-example-placeholder-single" required>
                     <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->category }}</option>
                     <option value="Berries">Berries</option>
                     <option value="Tropical Fruits">Tropical Fruits</option>
                     <option value="Citrus Fruits">Citrus Fruits</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
    
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger label-btn me-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="ri-close-line me-2"></i>Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="ri-checkbox-circle-line me-2"></i> <span>Save Changes</span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried to this

```
$(function(){
  $('.js-example-placeholder-single').select2({
      dropdownParent: $('#edit{id}')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the jQuery selector should be dynamic to match each modals unique ID so we can use a class for the select element and then iterate over each instance.. I think something like below should work

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-example-placeholder-single').each(function() {
        var $select = $(this);
        var modalId = $select.closest('.modal').attr('id');
        $select.select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#' + modalId)
        });
    });
});
```